# PhpStorm simultaneously create folder and file?

Tags: file, editor, phpstorm, creation

I come from a sublime text background where I had a plugin to create a file by just giving a path. If you gave it a path like:

```
test/foobar/file.txt
```

It would create the test and foobar folders automatically and simultaneously while I created this file.txt

Is there a way to do the same in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly that from the new file dialog.

Just enter the full path as the file name and it will create the folders as necessary.

Tested on PhpStorm 9